“Potential memory leak” warning
I created this little piece of code to test a copyMemZone function, which allows me to extract data from a memory zone.
In the example below, the parameters are entered manually (for tests), but this code must be used in a more complete program.
I don't feel like I made an error, and yet Qt Creator shows me the following message:

Potential leak of memory pointed to by 'dataSource' [clang-analyzer-unix.Malloc]

For the following line:
unsigned char* dataDest = (unsigned char*)malloc(sizeMaxDest*sizeof(unsigned char));`  

Is this message normal?
Did I write my code wrong?
int copyMemZone(unsigned char* zoneSourceFonc, size_t debutSourceFonc, size_t finSourceFonc, unsigned char** zoneDestFonc);
int copyMemZone(unsigned char *zoneSourceFonc, size_t debutSourceFonc, size_t finSourceFonc, unsigned char **zoneDestFonc)
{
  // Initialization
  int cursorMem = 0;

  if(finSourceFonc>debutSourceFonc)
  {
    // For each Character to Copy
    for (size_t i = debutSourceFonc; i < finSourceFonc; i++)
    {
      // Memorization
      (*zoneDestFonc)[cursorMem] = zoneSourceFonc[i];
      cursorMem++;
    }
  }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int main()
{
  // Initialization
  int sizeSource  = 10;                     // Size of Source Memory
  int beginMemo   = 2;  int endMemo   = 8;  // Parameters to copy (to extract) caracters
  int sizeMaxDest = 10;                     // Size of Destination Memory


  // Memory Allocation
  unsigned char* dataSource = (unsigned char*)malloc(sizeSource*sizeof(unsigned char));
  if(dataSource==NULL) return EXIT_FAILURE;

  // Mémorisation
  dataSource[0] = '0';
  dataSource[1] = 'X';
  dataSource[2] = 'M';
  dataSource[3] = 'E';
  dataSource[4] = 'M';
  dataSource[5] = 'O';
  dataSource[6] = 'R';
  dataSource[7] = 'Y';
  dataSource[8] = '8';
  dataSource[9] = '7';


  // Memory Allocation
  unsigned char* dataDest = (unsigned char*)malloc(sizeMaxDest*sizeof(unsigned char));
  if(dataDest==NULL) return EXIT_FAILURE;
  int tailleDest          = endMemo-beginMemo;

  // Copying the Memory Area
  copyMemZone((unsigned char*)dataSource,beginMemo,endMemo,&dataDest);


  // Display after copying
  for(int i=0;i<tailleDest;i++) qDebug() << QChar(dataDest[i]);

  // Free Memory
  free(dataDest);
  free(dataSource);
}


in general you shouldn't use malloc\free in C++ at all. There are limited use case for std::mallocto allocate storage  but this whole code looks unnecessary. Entire functionality of program can be writen in four lines without use of any library or self-written functions. Why amemcpyanalogcopyMemZone` should exist,? The message is not from Qt, it's warning about potential "code smell" from compiler.

There is a potential return before the calls to free. That will technically leak the memory (but also ends the program, so we might not care much).

In modern C++ explicit use of malloc free is considered bad practice. Use of RAII pattern is recommended. When Qt API is not in use explict use of new and delete is also considered bad practice. In your case you should use std::vector<unsigned char>.

@Swift-FridayPie Yes you right. I can use this line memcpy(dataDest,dataSource+debutMemo,finMemo-debutMemo) to copy memory...? But I wanted to make a function because in this function I wanted to check a memory overflow. If I only allocate a size of 3 characters for my destination and I want to copy 5 characters into it, I wanted to detect an overflow error

@Juan yah, that's a tried-and-true C API pattern, to pass buffer + buffer size (there is actually analog of memcpy which does that - memcpy_s . In c++ that's done by using incapsulation.

You aren't freeing dataSource in case malloc to dataDest fails.
Also, better to use nullptr instead of NULL.
You should change the code to the following:
if (dataDest == nullptr)
{
    free(dataSource);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

Also, instead of dynamically allocating memory using malloc/new and freeing it later using free/delete, maybe it's better to use std::vector like follows:
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
  int sizeSource  = 10;  // Size of Source Memory
  int beginMemo   = 2;   // Parameters to copy (to extract) characters 
  int endMemo     = 8;   // Parameters to copy (to extract) characters
  int sizeMaxDest = 10;  // Size of Destination Memory

  std::vector<unsigned char> dataSource{'0', 'X', 'M', 'E', 'M', 'O', 'R', 'Y', '8', '7'};

  std::vector<unsigned char> dataDest;
  dataDest.reserve(sizeMaxDest);
  std::copy(dataSource.begin() + beginMemo, dataSource.begin() + endMemo, std::back_inserter(dataDest));

  for (unsigned char c : dataDest)
  {
    qDebug() << QChar(c);
  }
}


Thank you for these explanations and the example code using vectors

In modern C++ explicit use of malloc/free and new/delete is considered bad practice.
See:
C++ Core Guidelines

R.10: Avoid malloc() and free()
Reason
malloc() and free() do not support construction and destruction, and do not mix well with new and delete.

C++ Core Guidelines

R.11: Avoid calling new and delete explicitly
Reason
The pointer returned by new should belong to a resource handle (that can call delete). If the pointer returned by new is assigned to a plain/naked pointer, the object can be leaked.

In your case you should use std::vector<unsigned char>:
int main()
{
  int sizeSource  = 10;
  int beginMemo   = 2;  
  int endMemo   = 8;
  int sizeMaxDest = 10;

  std::vector<unsigned char> dataSource{ '0', 'X', 'M', 'E', 'M', 'O', 'R', 'Y', '8', '7'};

  std::vector<unsigned char> dataDest;
  int tailleDest          = endMemo-beginMemo;

  dataDest =  { dataSource.begin() + beginMemo, dataSource.begin() + endMemo};


  for(auto x : tailleDest) qDebug() << QChar(x);
}

In Qt there is exception form this rule. Qt has own memory management pattern, where QObjects are in parent child relation. Then explicit use of new is fine in Qt when parent is set (no delete is needed since parent is responsible for releasing object).
Off-topic:
Do not use comments if they just repeating what symbol name already states. This is pointless. Also commonest stating obvious things are just a noise. As Uncle Bob says: "Comment is a failure of programmer to express his intent directly in a code.". So comments are useful to add information which is not clearly read form code (symbol names).

In the for loop, you probably meant dataDest instead of tailleDest.

Thank you for all this information. In fact I have to work on a Project in C++ under QT Environment but with functions already provided to me and written in C. And so I didn't think at all about using vectors to store this data returned by these functions
